# Java home path differs

Tags: java, intellij-idea

Hello I try to execute my project with bootRun on IntelliJ and I get the followign error:

```
       Execution failed for task ':bootRun'.
    > Process 'command '/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-    1.8.0.101-1.b14.fc24.x86_64/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
```

I checked the results of my JAVA paths and stuff and here there are

```
         echo $JAVA_HOME


      /home/mypc123/Downloads/jdk1.8.0_101/bin/java
       $ which java
       /usr/bin/java
```

I have jdk1.8.0 in /usr/bin

I looked more indepth and found this:

```
       ERROR org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool - Unable to create initial connections of pool.
      org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: role "syn12" does not exist
```

However when I connect to postgresql I have syn12 role and all my gradle JVM's are in the form usr/lib/jvm/java.......

Well we got down to this :  Can't load library: /opt/symmetry/ste/java/libste-java.so ,how can I install this library?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you have your project JDK pointed to another installation. The second issue is most likely different, like an incorrect JDBC url that happens to point to another, existing, database schema in which the required role does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Intellij IDEA doesn't use the $JAVA_HOME from your system but relies on [its own JDK definitions](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.2/defining-a-jdk-and-a-mobile-sdk-in-intellij-idea.html).

It looks like your application is not starting because of the SQL error you found in the logs, and Spring Boot returns 1 because it failed to start.

Comment: Error creating bean with name 'steObjectPool': Bean instantiation via constructor failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationE , that is what I get from the logs